# Check if saving to camera roll was successfull

Tags: ios, swift, camera, privacy, phphotolibrary

How do I check if a user was able to save to the camera roll during an `activityViewController`?

For example, I have an activity view controller that offers the option to save to the camera roll. After the user saves the picture, my app displays a prompt letting the user know that the image was saved. However, when the users click on the "save to camera roll" icon, he gets prompted by the OS to give permissions so my app can store photos on their camera roll. If the user rejects the permission, the `activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler` still returns success, even thought the user didn't save the picture into the camera.

How can I check if the user was actually able to save the picture to the camera roll?

```
activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
                if success {
                    if let activity = activity {
                        switch activity {
                        case .postToFacebook:
                            self.view.showToast(with: "Successfully posted to Facebook.")
                        case .postToTwitter:
                            self.view.showToast(with: "Successfully posted to Twitter.")
                        case .message:
                            self.view.showToast(with: "Your message has been sent.")
                        case .mail:
                            self.view.showToast(with: "Your email has been sent.")
                        case .saveToCameraRoll:
                            if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
                                self.view.show(alertForDeniedPermission(to: .photoLibraryAccess), animated: true)
                            } else {
                                self.view.showToast(with: "Your picture has been saved.")
                            }
                        default:
                            self.view.showToast(with: "Success!")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Checking for `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()` doesn't work since the enum is always `. notDetermined`. I think because my app is only asking for `Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description` and not `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`.

Comment: you will need these 3 in the plist 

1 - Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
2 - Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description
3 - Privacy - Media Library Usage Description

Comment: The code that u have written is supposed to post the image to facebook. Right ? why would it be saved to camera roll ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to *save* a photo to the photo library you will need the "*Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description*" and *Privacy - Media Library Usage Description* set in your Info.plist file too.

Your app is showing not determined for the authorization status, because the user can not grant nor deny your access, because you haven't asked for it yet!

Just to give you some context, here are the different cases with explanations that the authorization status can return: 
(taken from the [Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phauthorizationstatus) website.)

case **not determined**: Explicit user permission is required for photo library access, but the user has not yet granted or denied such permission.

case **restricted**: Your app is not authorized to access the photo library, and the user cannot grant such permission.

case **denied**: The user has explicitly denied your app access to the photo library.

case **authorized**: The user has explicitly granted your app access to the photo library.